# "Sorry my bot code is having issues" message on calling PromptDialog.Choice()

Tags: c#, botframework

Code flow is as follows:

- I have a `DialogA` which calls a qnaMaker Dialog in its `StartAsync` method.
- The qnaMaker Dialog callback calls `promptDialog` function in a helper class(which is not a Dialog by the way)
- Once user selects appropriate choice on the prompt, a callback is called which post a message
- Error appears after the message("Helpful"/ "Not helpful") has been posted

My first incination was to use `context.Wait()` after the message has been posted from `OnOptionSelectedForPrompt` callback, bit it seems that calling wait here somehow executes the `ResumeAfter` callback for `DialogA`.

Code Sample: **DialogA.cs**

```
[Serializable]
    public class DialogA : IDialog<object>
    {
        private string tool = "sometool";
        private string userInput = String.Empty;
        private bool sendToQnaMaker = false;

        public DialogA(string userQuery)
        {
            if (userQuery.Length > 0)
            {
                sendToQnaMaker = true;
                userInput = userQuery;
            }
        }

        public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            if(sendToQnaMaker)
            {
                await context.Forward(new QnaDialog(), QnaMakerDialogCallback, BotHelper.CreateMessageActivityForQnaMaker(userInput), CancellationToken.None);
            } else
            {
                await BotHelper.ShowWelcomeMessageOnMenuSection(context, tool);
                context.Wait(OnMessageReceived);
            }
        }

    private async Task QnaMakerDialogCallback(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var response = await result;
        bool isInQnaMaker = Convert.ToBoolean(response);
        BotHelper botHelper = new BotHelper(tool);
        botHelper.showPrompt(context)
    }
```

**BotHelper.cs**

```
    public void showPrompt(IDialogContext context)
    {

        PromptDialog.Choice(context, OnOptionSelectedForPrompt, Constants.promptChoices, MiscellaneousResponses.answerFeedbackMessage, MiscellaneousResponses.invalidOptionMessage, 3);
    }

    public async Task OnOptionSelectedForPrompt(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {
            string optionSelected = await result;

            switch (optionSelected)
            {
                case MiscellaneousResponses.helpfulMessage:
                    string botreply = "Helpful";
                    await context.PostAsync(botreply);
                    break;
                case MiscellaneousResponses.notHelpfulMessage:
                    string botResponse = "Not Helpful";
                    await context.PostAsync(botResponse);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a separate dialog instead of using the `BotHelper` class and properly handled dialog stack using `Context.Done` and `Context.Wait`.